# Does npm automcatically download a version that is compatible with the Node version on the local computer?

Tags: node.js, npm

Does npm automatically download the version of the library that is compatible with the Nodejs environment?

Suppose the most recent version is only compatible with Nodejs18 or above but the Nodejs version on my computer is v14. When I run `npm i <library>`, does npm automatically download a version of the library that is compatible with Node14, or do I have to manually lookup a version and run `npm i <library>@version`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't.

If you run `npm i <library>` it will pull in the latest version of the library irrespective of which version of Node you have on your machine. To install a specific version of the library you will need to run `npm i <library>@version`.

We can actually prove that this is the case. The [jsdom package](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) upped its required Node version from v12 to v14 when it released version 20.0. You can see the release notes [here](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/releases/tag/20.0.0).

The way that a package specifies the supported version of Node is through an `engines` property in the `package.json` file.

Version 19 ([link](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/19.0.0/package.json#L114)):

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=12"
}
```

Version 20 ([link](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/20.0.0/package.json#L114)):

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=14"
}
```

So with the latest version of Node:

```
$ node -v
v19.6.0

$ npm i jsdom
...

$ cat package.json | grep jsdom
"jsdom": "^21.1.0"
```

As expected, the latest version of jsdom is installed.

Then, using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to change Node version:

```
$ nvm install v12
Now using node v12.22.12 (npm v6.14.16)

$ node -v
v12.22.12

$ npm init -y
...

$ npm i jsdom
...

$ cat package.json | grep jsdom
"jsdom": "^21.1.0"
```

As you can see, this has still pulled in the latest version of jsdom, despite me running a version of Node that the current jsdom doesn't support.